# Powershell and Psession

Tags: web-services, powershell

I have a powershell script that pulls in a server list with the following headers.  computername,optype,opname. I then loop through and if I have a format of server,service,service name then start/stop the service. If I have a format of server,script,script_path_name then I am trying to use an invoke-command to run that script. However I need somehow establish a remote session ... Here is the error txt that I get.

> [c1399] Connecting to remote server c1399 failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the 
>   request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management 
>   service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to 
>   analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
>     + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (c1399:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConnect,PSSessionStateBroken

Here is the *current* code I am using...

```
elseif($computer.optype -eq "script")
{      
    write-host  running script $computer.opname on $computer.computername  
    $Status = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer.computername -ScriptBlock { . $computer.opname }
    Write-Output "Script execution status for $($computer.name) is $Status" >> C:\Scripts\RMLog.txt
}
```

Comment: Have you done what the error message is telling you to do? Have you enabled PSRemoting on the remote computer(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Enabled power shell remoting on the server.
To enable PowerShell Remoting, run the following command,

Enable-PSRemoting -Force

Please refer below link for more details
http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/

http://powershelltutorial.net/V2/Powershell-With-TFS

this will solve your issue..